# I want to search the database table with masked (XXXX-XX-XX) date by using c# or sql

Tags: c#, sql

My date column datatype is "nvarchar". My date column value will be like `XXXX-XX-XX`(YYYY-MM-DD). Here XX's is any number like `2018-XX-01`

My table contains below records

```
ID DOB
-- ------------
 1  2018-01-01
 2  2018-04-01
 3  2018-XX-01
```

Scenario 1 
When I query the date `2018-01-01` at that time I want below output

```
2018-01-01
2018-XX-01
```

because XX is any no.

Scenario 2
When I query the date `2018-XX-01` at that time I want below output

```
2018-01-01
2018-XX-01
2018-04-01
```

because XX is any no

Here XX's will be at any position like at Year, Month, Day.

Can anyone please provide the solution either in SQL or C#.

Comment: _"My date column datatype is "nvarchar""_ .... that'll be your first mistake then. Use the provided `datetime` type. It exists for several good reasons. Dates are not strings, except when being viewed by humans, or transported in a text-only format such as XML or JSON.

Comment: Why do you store dates as `nvarchar`?

Comment: Anyway, which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Other? Please specify using the right tags. The syntax you need might be different in each case. Also what have you researched or tried so far? We like to _help_ you solve your problem but this isn't really a site to just get free labour without any effort - "give me the solution" is not really a good request to make and will likely attract downvotes or close votes. Instead tell us what you've done so far, and what specific problem you're facing?

Comment: I assume *DOB* stands for *Date Of Birth*, therefore I wonder why you would have it stored like `2018-XX-01` as if you didn't know the month but still you know the day ("*Hey, I'm born on [oops forgot] the 1st, 2018!*")

Comment: Yes I agree with Rafalon, storing an incomplete date like `2018-XX-01` like this makes no sense logically. If you're getting input like that you need to insist on more accurate info from your users. Or maybe the situation is different - perhaps if you explained what the data is actually representing, and what you're trying to achieve, we could suggest a solution that's compliant with database design principles but still achieves your overall goal.

Comment: Ya I accept your comments....

Comment: @RahulJadhav . . . I think the downvotes are nasty.  This is actually a good question about wildcards with dates.  I suspect people are too hung up on storing a date as a string, when what the OP wants to do cannot be stored as a date.  The data representation might not be what I would choose, but it is reasonable for the problem.

Comment: @Raflon Ya I accept your comments....But here this is the client requirement and we need to take date column as nvarchar only. Because there can be a scenario when the person don't know about "Year/Month/Day" of Birth. So we are saving the Year/Month/Day as XX in DB as an unknown Year/Month/Day.

Comment: @RahulJadhav in that situation it might be a reasonable approach to actually separate the values into separate fields for Year, Month and Day, then you can have NULL in the fields where the exact value is not known, and you can search by (combinations of) the known values in your queries

Comment: Why don't you have NULL when the date is unknown, and otherwise use a date? You should be the expert providing the database requirements, not the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think you can use `like`, but in both directions:

```
where @datestr like replace(dob, 'XX', '%') or
      dob like replace(@datestr, 'XX', '%')
```

Comment: It works for me thank you very much for the quick and perfect solution. As I am new in sql that's why I was struggling in this.... Thanks once agian :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution using IEqualityComparer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DOB", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,"2018-01-01"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2,"2018-04-01"} );
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "2018-XX-01" });

            MyDate myDate = new MyDate();
            var results1 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => myDate.Equals(x.Field<string>("DOB"),"2018-01-01"))
                .ToList();

            var results2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(x => myDate.Equals(x.Field<string>("DOB"), "2018-XX-01"))
                 .ToList();

        }
    }
    public class MyDate : IEqualityComparer  
    {

        public new Boolean Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            string[] dateArrayX = ((string)x).Split(new char[] { '-' });
            string[] dateArrayY = ((string)y).Split(new char[] { '-' });

            Boolean yearCompare = (dateArrayX[0] == "XXXX") | (dateArrayY[0] == "XXXX") | (dateArrayX[0] == dateArrayY[0]);
            Boolean monthCompare = (dateArrayX[1] == "XX") | (dateArrayY[1] == "XX") | (dateArrayX[1] == dateArrayY[1]);
            Boolean dayCompare = (dateArrayX[2] == "XX") | (dateArrayY[2] == "XX") | (dateArrayX[2] == dateArrayY[2]);

            return yearCompare & monthCompare & dayCompare;

        }
        public int GetHashCode(object obj)
        {
            return obj.ToString().ToLower().GetHashCode();
        }
    }



}
```